# How to set full width divs inside horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

so I get some problem with the horizontal scroll, I read a lot about the fixed-width items inside the scroll containers but what about next thing:
how to write styles that will be automatically set the width of non-fixed-width items like (item with classes weeks and date)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.container__columns {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
}

.container__rows {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  color: #000;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.weeks,
.date {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.weeks {
  background: lightgrey;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.date {
  background: lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__columns">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
    <div class="col">7</div>
    <div class="col">8</div>
    <div class="col">9</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container__rows">
    <div class="weeks">
      Week 1
    </div>

    <div class="date">
      Augest 23, 1998, 24 - hours
    </div>

    <div class="container__columns">
      <div class="col">1</div>
      <div class="col">2</div>
      <div class="col">3</div>
      <div class="col">4</div>
      <div class="col">5</div>
      <div class="col">6</div>
      <div class="col">7</div>
      <div class="col">8</div>
      <div class="col">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the next thing: the CSS which will be set items with classes date and weeks to full width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider `inline-flex;` for the inner container and remove `flex` for the main container as it's not really needed in your case.

```css
.container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.container__columns {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container__rows {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col {
  width:250px;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  color: #000;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.weeks,
.date {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.weeks {
  background: lightgrey;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.date {
  background: lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__columns">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
    <div class="col">7</div>
    <div class="col">8</div>
    <div class="col">9</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container__rows">
    <div class="weeks">
      Week 1
    </div>

    <div class="date">
      Augest 23, 1998, 24 - hours
    </div>

    <div class="container__columns">
      <div class="col">1</div>
      <div class="col">2</div>
      <div class="col">3</div>
      <div class="col">4</div>
      <div class="col">5</div>
      <div class="col">6</div>
      <div class="col">7</div>
      <div class="col">8</div>
      <div class="col">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndriiSiuta use `inline-block` the key is the `inline-*`

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/fLkpmy4d/3/) - how to fix this case? Inline not works :(

Comment: @AndriiSiuta same as I did, you need to remove flex from the container:https://jsfiddle.net/o9asx7fj/1/ and also replace `flex:0 0 250px` with `width:250px`